# Create users with pl/sql procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need help with pl/sql procedures. I created a procedure that will automatically generate username and password for new clients when the clients table is inserted into. The procedure is initialised via a trigger which executes the procedure. Problem is the insert into client table happens ok but username and password are not generated. I have have to run procedure after the insert for that to happen.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_new_clients 
var_assign_user clients VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
FOR my_c IN (SELECT client_fname, client_lname FROM clients) 
LOOP
var_assign_user := 'CREATE USER "' || my_c.client_fname || '" IDENTIFIED BY "' || my_c.client_lname|| '"';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_assign_user; COMMIT;
END LOOP;
END procedure_new_clients;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_new_clients
AFTER INSERT ON clients
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.client_id NOT NULL)

DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

BEGIN
procedure_new_clients();

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You procedure completes in autonomous transaction. At that moment first transaction which inserts into client has not finished, so autononmous transaction can't see new record.